# Fujitsu Life book Debian Weezy 64-bit

Tags: debian, 64bit, hardware-compatibility

Has anyone managed to get a 64 bit Linux installation on the Fujitsu Lifebook A3130 Currently have 32-bit Debian Wheezy but having troubles with building/Compiling Android and CyanogenMod.

Having consulted with xda-developers, it is suggested that I upgrade to 64-bit. There is just very little info I've been able to find so far about this laptop and 64-bit Linux, although the documentation for the processor says it is compatible.

Comment: Is your Q Debian specific, or just 64-bit in general?

Comment: Is there any reason to assume it won't work? I just had a [quick look](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/fujitsu-lifebook-a3130-15/4505-3121_7-32825804.html) but it doesn't seem like you have any strange hardware. Have you tried a live CD as @slm suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I too found literally no results when searching for ["Fujitsu Lifebook A3130 64 bit linux"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Fujitsu%20Lifebook%20A3130%2064%20bit%20linux&oq=Fujitsu%20Lifebook%20A3130%2064%20bit%20linux&aqs=chrome.0.57.8204j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and the results for ["Fujitsu Lifebook A3130 linux"](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&safe=off&q=Fujitsu%20Lifebook%20A3130%20linux&oq=Fujitsu%20Lifebook%20A3130%20linux&gs_l=serp.3...54943.55900.0.56233.7.7.0.0.0.0.96.568.7.7.0....0...1c.1.32.serp..6.1.83.Nxixp63N98c) weren't all that impressive either, so I'd be a little gun shy to try this out by jumping in 100%.

#### What to do?

I think I'd rather do the following to start, which is what I do when ever I'm suspicious of getting full support of Linux under hardware X.

First, I'll typically start out with the live DVD/CD version of a distro to confirm that that is working 100% to my liking, prior to doing a bare metal installation.

Next, I'll use a tool such as [GParted](http://gparted.org/), to squeeze my current installation down enough so that there is enough free room to do a bare metal install on the system. This route can be a bit more time consuming but leaves me with an exit plan, if/when the OS I'm attempting to install doesn't work out as planned.

If the above testing works out to my liking, then I'll make the commitment to fully install the OS, this time devoting the entire HDD to the OS if that's the direction I'm aiming to go.

Comment: @drewbenn - I realize he asked about Debian in the title, but the body of the Q seemed more 64-bit and not just Debian. So I approached it like that. Also the OP hadn't bothered to tag the Q as Debian, I see you've edited that, and I approved the edit, but we should probably get full clarification from OP if that matters at all.